# How can i separate methods of a class in separate files?

Tags: python, class, module

Let's say we have this class:

```
Class example:
       def __init__(self):
             self.var = 23
```

How can i access this variable within a function in another file by importing it in the main file?

```
def my_func():
       pass
```

In fact i want the "my_func()" to be a method of the "example" class but in a separate file.

Comment: There's no normal way to do this. You're not supposed to be able to declare a method as part of a class, _outside_ of that class.

Comment: So you mean there is no way to devide a class to separate files?

Comment: You could use an `__init__` for your entire module, and import things to that to make sure that all your methods are part of the same module, but no, there's no way I know of to divide a single _class_ into two separate files. To my knowledge, this is the same in most object-oriented programming languages. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: My class consists of very large methods, i want to separate those methods to separate files so that my my main file is cleaner.

Comment: This is very much doable, but generally discouraged because it breaks assumptions of other developers. If your methods are so large they warrant separate *files*, they and by extension the class are most certainly doing too much at once. Consider to improve your application design (SOLID seems applicable), not the layout of the existing design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to split your class into two classes that have no data of their own—only methods—so although you inherit them, you never have to call super() on them. This classes are called "mixins"

## _example.py

```
class Mixin:

    def my_func(self):
        print(self._b)
```

## example.py

```
import _example

class Example(_example.Mixin):

    def __init__(self):
        self._a = 1
        self._b = 2
        self._c = 3
```

Now you can do:

```
ex = Example()
ex.my_func() # This will print "2" on console.
```

You can check different aproaches [here](http://www.qtrac.eu/pyclassmulti.html)